# ValueChanged and ValueEpression in blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have seen the use of ValueChanged and ValueExpression in blazor component but does not have any idea wy they are used and what does ValueChanged and ValueEpression do in blazor? 
If any body can explain them in simple language, it would be really a great help/

Comment: check this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658450/when-to-use-valuechanged-and-valueexpression-in-blazor

Comment: @AL.Sharie what is bound value in the answer can you help me

Comment: [AL.Sharie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15116229/al-sharie) [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66410717/3744182), *check this link to know more about data binding https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/?view=aspnetcore-5.0&viewFallbackFrom=aspnetcore-3.0#data-binding*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check the [InputBase Class Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.forms.inputbase-1?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

- ***ValueChanged**: Gets or sets a callback that updates the bound value.*
- ***ValueExpression**: Gets or sets an expression that identifies the bound value.*

Generally, Razor components provide data binding features via an HTML element attribute named `@bind` with a field, property, or Razor expression value, we could use it to bind values to the html elements. If we are not using the `bind` attribute, we could use the `ValueExpression` and `ValueChanged` to update the bound value. Please refer to the following sample:

```
<EditForm Model="form">
    <p>Current value: @form.MyProperty</p>
    <InputSelect ValueChanged="@((string s) => DoThing(s))"
                 ValueExpression="@(()=> form.MyProperty)">
        <option value="0">0</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="200">200</option>
        <option value="300">300</option>
    </InputSelect> 
</EditForm>

@code {
    MyForm form = new MyForm(); //create an model instance.

    void DoThing(string s) //value changed event.
    {
        form.MyProperty = s; //get the current selected value and assign to the Model.
    }
    //define a class to get/set the dropdownlist selected value.
    public class MyForm
    {
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    } 
}
```

If using the `@bind` attribute, the sample code as below:

```
    <p>Current Season: @model.Season</p>
    <InputSelect @bind-Value="model.Season">
        @foreach (var value in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Season)))
        {
            <option>@value</option>
        }
    </InputSelect>

@code { 
    Model model = new Model();    
    class Model
    {
        public Season Season { get; set; }
    }    
    enum Season
    {
        Spring,
        Summer,
        Autumn,
        Winter
    } 
}
```

The screenshot as below:

[image]

Reference:

[ASP.NET Core Blazor data binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Comment: ValueChanged: Gets or sets a callback that updates the bound value. What is this bound value means. Please can you tell me actually I am not getting it that what does it mean

Comment: The bound value is the value of  bind to the [Input component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/forms-validation?view=aspnetcore-5.0#built-in-forms-components), for example, the InputText component will be rendered as the `<input type="text">` element, then, we can use `<InputText Class="form-control" Value="@Value">` to bind value for the InputText component, the `@Value` is used to bound a value to the input element's value attribute, the value is the bound value.