# MatTextField - how to detect the value is changed?

Tags: c#, matblazor

How to track the changes on MatTextField? I have bind-value, but how to set up ValueChanged?
I can't find answer anywhere. Some example will be helpful as I am newbie with Blazor.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60970886/2983568) help?

Comment: It is little confusing. I don't know how to use it.