# How to add an on change event to an inputRadio?

Tags: c#, html, input, blazor

Does anybody know how to add an on change event to an inputRadio?

I know you can do the following

```
<input type="radio" @onchange="ChangeFunction"/>
```

and this will hit  the `ChangeFunction()` however if I do the following

```
<InputRadioGroup @bind-Value="@i.LeaveRequest.DayTime">
    <label>Full Day</label>
    <InputRadio Value="@FullDay" class="checkbox-P" @onchange="ChangeFunction"/>
</InputRadioGroup>
```

it never hits the function.

I've also tried adding `@onchange="ChangeFunction"` to the `InputRadioGroup` line however neither seem to hit the function.

Anyone got any idea how to do this?

Comment: You can  attach `onchange` to the InputRadioGroup if you don't use  `bind`!

Comment: @user13256346 Could you provide an example? This is located in an editForm so I need to have the selected value in the model submitted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create normal radio buttons:

```
@foreach (var item in new string[] {"AspNetCore","AspNet","SomeJsThingWhatever"})
 {
  <div>
      <input type="radio" name="technology" id="@item" value="@item" 
         @onchange="RadioSelection" 
         checked=@(RadioValue.Equals(item,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
         />
      <label for="@item">@item</label>
   </div>
 }
<div>
   <label>Selected Value is @RadioValue</label>
</div>
 @functions
 {
   string RadioValue = "aspnetcore";
    void RadioSelection(ChangeEventArgs args)
    {
      RadioValue = args.Value.ToString();
    }
  }
```

[Source](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/3b18q1ix)

Answer (score 3):

Blazor page

```
<EditForm Model="Items">
<InputRadioGroup ValueChanged="@((e) => OnRadiochange(e))" TValue="string" ValueExpression="() => SelectedValue">
    @foreach (var item in Items)
    {
        bool Checked= false;
        if (SelectedValue.Equals(item, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            Checked = true;
        }
    <div class="form-check">
        <InputRadio Value="@item" class="form-check-input" checked=@Checked />
        @item <br />
    </div>
    }
</InputRadioGroup>
```

Code behind

```
public string SelectedValue { get; set; } = "AspNetCore";
public List<string> Items { get; set; } = new List<string> { "AspNetCore", "AspNet", "SomeJsThingWhatever" };

    private void OnRadiochange(object sender)
    {
        SelectedValue = (string)sender;
        StateHasChanged();
    }
```

Comment: Yep. This has worked. I have done a mix of both. The radio such as `<input type="radio" name="dayTime_@i.CalendarDay" class="checkbox-P" id="@FullDay" value="@FullDay"
                                       @onchange="EventArgs => { SelectionChanged(EventArgs, i); }" />` and then setting the value that I submit in the form in the onchange function

Comment: @JamesS, I fixed the second solution and works right now correct, please check it!

Comment: I tried your solution, however, I had the situation where, after I'd trigger the OnRadiochange handler, that the option group would not have the value selected anymore! All option buttons would be blank! And the SelectedValue would be good.

I fixed it by adding also the `Value="SelectedValue"` in combination with `ValueExpression="() => SelectedValue"` and that did the trick.

Additional explanations why here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60658450/when-to-use-valuechanged-and-valueexpression-in-blazor